# How to keep polling GitHub repository and get commits by its messages on a regular interval using Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, github, devops

I need to know how to write a Jenkins job which polls a GitHub repository continuously(say once in 4 hours) and send an email of commits(only the commit messages) made to that repo.

Answer (score 0):

First the polling part:

In your job configuration, you can check of Poll SCM, and in that box enter values that would poll your repository every 4 hours, such as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

The second part about sending the commit message:

As far as I am aware Jenkins always grabs the latest commit with the latest commit message. You could get the latest commit message from running "git log -1" inside of a shell command and storing it inside of an environment variable and then including that environment variable in your email body.

Here is a list of default environment variables that you can use throughout your job or also include in your email: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-belowJenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables

Comment: Its not only the latest commit, I need all the commits made to that repo in that 4 hour interval.

Comment: So with that you could just update the "git log" shell command to grab all commits from the last four hours, something like: 

git log --pretty=format:"%ad - %an: %s" --after="CURRENT_TIME-4" --until="CURRENT_TIME"